# nuxt.js 3 error page and error handling /throw

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am new for nuxt.js3
I want to use error.vue to display the error occured in /pages/index.vue, but it seems not working, when error occurs i
can see error on console.log , but it is not redirected to error.vue , does any one have some ideas?

thank you in advance!

below is example code

#### pages/index.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
async function initLoadAPI() {
  try {
   // doing axios call here ......
  }
  catch (error: any) {
    if (isAxiosError(error))
      console.error('There was an axios error!', error.response?.data || error)
    else
      console.error('There was a general error!', error)
    throw createError({ statusCode: 500, statusMessage: 'BackEnd Error', fatal: true })
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('Component is mounted!')
  initLoadAPI()
})
<script>
```

#### error.vue

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  error: Object,
})

const handleError = () => clearError({ redirect: '/' })
</script>
```

Comment: Does anything on this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15432) help?